# Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'sectionHeaderTopPadding'

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode12, ios15

Why I am getting build error from Xcode 12.4 (simulator ios 14.x) for the following code?

```
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        myTableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0 // error here
    }
```

The error was,

> Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'sectionHeaderTopPadding'

If ios 15 is not available Xcode is supposed to skip compiling this code. Isnt it?

Comment: Try updating xcode which will also update the swift version. your code is working fine. my xcode version is 13.2.1 and swift version 5.5.2

Comment: @AbdulMomen what max version of swift Xcode 12.4 supports?

Comment: xcode 12.4 does not support iOS 15. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_4-release-notes

Comment: @AbdulMomen that was not the answer for my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a condition for compilation

```swift
#if compiler(>=5.5)
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    myTableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0
}
#endif
```

Comment: Great! I will check and let you know the result. Btw, how did you know that xcode 12.4 supports max swift version 5.5? How can we know it?

Comment: It works. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: btw, how can I use this in objective C .m file?

Comment: I don't know if we can check the swift version in objc 

Answer (score 3):

Because xCode 12.x supports max iOS 14.x development, so how can your xCode know what is provided in iOS 15.x

If you are working with a team member and your teammate have xCode 13.x then either you can update your xCode to use the this code, or you can comment this code and then build from your xCode (12.x).

Comment: Interesting. Why xcode engineers do not support forward compatibility for this feature? In fact xcode12 doesn’t need to know ios15 API. If engineers of xcode knows which versions are they going to release in future they can easily tackle this issue. Once compiler finds the condition unsatisfied it just need to ignore the code or treat it as a comment internally. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update your XCODE version to 13

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This won't build as Xcode 12.4 is shipped with iOS14 and is not aware of the presence of "sectionHeaderTopPadding" in iOS 15. You will have to install Xcode 13 to successfully build this.